# game loop semi fixed time step understanding

Tags: java

I have an game loop that does nothing but just analyze no of updates and time taken to render an frame. Here is the main class

```
public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
{
  Clock clock=new Clock(Math.pow(10,9),80);

  double delta=0;
  int updates=0;
  long timer1=System.currentTimeMillis();

  while(true)
  {
   long frameTime=clock.getDelta(); 

   delta+=clock.getDeltaUpdate(frameTime);
   while(delta>=1)
   {   
    updates++;  
    delta--;   
   }

   if(System.currentTimeMillis()-timer1>=1000)
   {   
    updates=0;
    timer1+=1000;
   }        
  }
 }
```

Here is the class Clock.java

```
public class Clock
{
  private long
  previous=0,
  current=0;

  private final double updateCount;

  Clock(double timing,double updates)
  {
   current=System.nanoTime();
   previous=current;

   updateCount=timing/updates;
  }

  long getDelta()
  {
   current=System.nanoTime();
   long delta=current-previous;
   previous=current;

   return delta;
  }

  double getDeltaUpdate(long delta){return delta/updateCount;}
}
```

Here is how I understand it using simple linear algebra

Let's say

```
In  1000000000ns(1 second)   ->    60 Frames to be rendered(This is our target)

 Therefore  In (X)ns          ->    1 Frame to be rendered
```

And  by simple cross multiplication

```
        60X=1000000000ns

        X=1000000000/60
```

Which means we want our main loop to take 1000000000/60(ns) to render an frame
Which is our target

But our system takes it's own time to render an frame. Let's say at one specific
frame it takes 135ns to render an frame. Therefore by using linear algebra

Let y=(1000000000/60) be the time we want our system to take to render 1 frame. Therefore

```
Our Goal     In   y(ns)      ->  1 Frame Should be rendered



But System   In   135(ns)    ->  k(No of subframes to be rendered to make same 

                                   amount of progress as in y(ns) of time)
```

Therefore  by cross multiplication

```
k*y=135ns      ->       k=135ns/y  ->   i.e  ->  135ns/(1000000000)/60

or k  =   (135ns*60)/1000000000
```

So k tell's us no of updates/steps to take in an single frame so as to simulate some 60 steps of physics in 1000ms even if system takes varying amount of time to render an frame

hence in the main class we have the line of code

```
delta+=clock.getDeltaUpdate(frameTime);
```

where clock.getDeltaUpdate(long) return's 'k' 
and variable "frametime" is the time
system takes to render one frame(in our example 135ns)

The one concept I don't understand is why are we doing

```
delta+=
```

and not simply

```
delta=
```

what I believe is unsimulated(fractional value of k)updates from our previous frame would get added into our next frame which should cause incorrect no of updates for concecutive frames but that's not the case and it doesn't work

can anyone plzz explain why delta+= work's and delta= dosen't?

Sorry for wasting anybody's time here but i'm really am a nobe when it comes to math's

Also in LWJGL 2.9.3 we have an function called Display.sync(int) which caps our

fps.

Is it possible to implement that feature in this game loop?

Thanking u.

Comment: "Plzzz" don't get all TXT SPK on us.

Comment: I'm so sorry. just want to give u all the details that's all

Comment: It's just a lot easier for people to understand if you spell it out in full. Some people depend on translation tools and screen readers. Others are just allergic to that sort of shorthand.

Comment: Will do that but the question is in the main code and it's just one line. People who already know how this work's don't have to read my explanation.I hope so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I misunderstood the concept of delta. It doesn't give the number of sub updates that need's to executed per frame but rather the percentage of frames that has been completed The system produces time[in nanoseconds] and my game loop consumes it[in milliseconds].

In my Clock.getDeltaUpdate() method delta gives the time taken to render an frame and updateCount is an misleading name but rather it contain's the time our system should take to render an frame.
So if we divide

```
Time Taken By system per frame(delta)/Time we want per frame(update count)
```

We get an percentage value containing how many frames our system has rendered. After that we need to only iterate that many frames and progress our animation.

delta+ is needed to progress time forward(by delta nano seconds) so that our accumulator can complete one frame worth of time otherwise delta= would assign an absolute time(in nano seconds) hence our game clock would never get to an frame unless our system was very slow